# Is Physical path of adding a new site compulsory placed inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot?

Tags: iis, iis-7

When adding a new web application on IIS 7.5, I need to locate my physical path of my web application.

Is it compulsory that the web application folder has to be placed inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HttpServerUtility.MapPath` function.

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx